# How to keep initial row order

Tags: r

I have run this SQL sentence through the package: sqldf

```
SELECT A,B, COUNT(*) AS NUM 
FROM DF
GROUP BY A,B
```

I have got the output I wanted, but I would like to keep the initial row order. Unfortunately, the output has a different order.

For example:

```
> DF
   A B   C D
1 11 2 432 4
2 11 3 432 4
3 13 4 241 5
4 42 5   2 3
5 51 5 332 2
6 51 5 332 1
7 51 5 332 1
> sqldf("SELECT A,B,C,D, COUNT (*)  AS NUM
+        FROM DF
+        GROUP BY A,B,C,D")
   A B   C D NUM
1 11 2 432 4   1
2 11 3 432 4   1
3 13 4 241 5   1
4 42 5   2 3   1
5 51 5 332 1   2
6 51 5 332 2   1
```

As you can see the row order changes, (row number 5 and 6). It would be great if someone could help me with this issue.

Regards,

Comment: There is no "initial row order" in the database.  You need to add an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: so, you would like to have the result ordered according to A or B or A,B or B,A?

Comment: @citizen show us the data and desired output. Your question is confusing

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I am using the package "sqldf" to insert SQL code in R

Comment: since you are using group by, 51 5 332 1 appears two times. It will return 2 @Citizen

Comment: It is right, but the row initial order changes, my question is whether there is a way to get the initial order

Comment: Again: there is no such thing as "the initial order" of rows in a relational database

Comment: Ok,  but I have a data frame as data and this data frame has an order. Keep in mind that I am inserting a piece of SQL code in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to use this with `sqldf`, use `ORDER.BY` with `names` pasted together

```
library(sqldf)
nm <- toString(names(DF))
DF1 <- cbind(rn = seq_len(nrow(DF)), DF)
nm1 <- toString(names(DF1))
fn$sqldf("SELECT $nm, COUNT (*)  AS NUM
    FROM DF1
    GROUP BY $nm ORDER BY $nm1")
#   A B   C D NUM
#1 11 2 432 4   1
#2 11 3 432 4   1
#3 13 4 241 5   1
#4 42 5   2 3   1
#5 51 5 332 2   1
#6 51 5 332 1   2
```

Comment: @Citizen I guess you wanted the same output as in the other question?

Comment: I would like the output I get in my question here, but with the initial row order

Comment: @Citizen `fn$sqldf("SELECT $nm1, COUNT (*)  AS NUM
        FROM DF
        GROUP BY $nm1")` not entirely sure what order you want

Comment: You get the same order I got, but not the initial row order, maybe there is not a way to do what I want.

Comment: @Citizen I think you need to create a sequence column first and then do the ordering

Comment: @Citizen The way I did is that I create a sequence column 'rn' and then do the 'COUNT" and order by all the columns along with the sequence column 'rn' so that it will be in the initial sequence

Comment: Thanks, it is a great solution. I have to run it in my code and check the entire code. cbind is ok, thanks again

Comment: @Citizen I added `cbind` but it can also be created in sqldf, but the only thing is that it is a bit round way to do that

Comment: SQLite provides a pseudo-column `rowid` that could be used to avoid creating the sequence column.